# How can I use code to get accurate "crs_transform" of ee.Images after the clip() operation?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, transform

I use GEE(Google Earth Engine) for my research. I found that the parameters "crs_transform" of the ee.Image did not change before and after the clip() operation.

```
print(ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT/LC08_121044_20220216').select("B2").getInfo())
print(ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT/LC08_121044_20220216').clip(region_of_interest).select("B2").getInfo())

# Print results:
# {'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'B2', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'int', 'min': 0, 'max': 65535}, 'dimensions': [7681, 7831], 'crs': 'EPSG:32650', 'crs_transform': [30, 0, 192585, 0, -30, 2674215]}], 'id': 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT/LC08_121044_20220216', 'version': 1645837933973575, 'properties': {'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5': 0.0062656, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6': 0.0015582, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3': 0.012142, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4': 0.010239, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1': 0.012867, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2': 0.013176, 'WRS_TYPE': 2, 'K2_CONSTANT_BAND_11': 1201.1442, 'K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10': 1321.0789, 'system:footprint': {'type': 'LinearRing', 'coordinates': [[114.42907316771655, 24.15608546786755], [114.41706095996588, 24.158416046147536], [114.41594448639428, 24.153971084604997], [114.31484977656712, 23.721562678953582], [114.21736195372864, 23.302418032220146], [114.12034350721427, 22.883251924578012], [114.02057521071433, 22.450136399001522], [114.01525196095562, 22.426845258690026], [114.26814673464122, 22.376024814437706], [115.09567502732617, 22.20664243739985], [115.81424634329359, 22.055744270343936], [115.81636286433974, 22.05575963371322], [115.92085144557515, 22.48462056120656], [115.99837644023208, 22.80133603646364], [116.1370618655942, 23.365131857246134], [116.21962697364333, 23.698855957800692], [116.24032549663825, 23.78309463315655], [116.24134384019862, 23.78791393104327], [116.24056413186268, 23.78862389083357], [115.58417296423728, 23.92452040711369], [114.42907316771655, 24.15608546786755]]}, 'REFLECTIVE_SAMPLES': 7681, 'SUN_AZIMUTH': 140.66864157, 'DATA_SOURCE_TIRS_STRAY_LIGHT_CORRECTION': 'TIRS', 'DATE_ACQUIRED': '2022-02-16', 'ELLIPSOID': 'WGS84', 'STATION_ID': 'LGN', 'RESAMPLING_OPTION': 'CUBIC_CONVOLUTION', 'ORIENTATION': 'NORTH_UP', 'WRS_ROW': 44, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9': 0.0024488, 'TARGET_WRS_ROW': 44, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7': 0.0005252, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8': 0.011587, 'IMAGE_QUALITY_TIRS': 9, 'TRUNCATION_OLI': 'UPPER', 'CLOUD_COVER': 49.99, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_VERIFY': 6.568, 'COLLECTION_CATEGORY': 'T1', 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_REFLECTIVE': 30, 'CLOUD_COVER_LAND': 38.22, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL': 7.876, 'COLLECTION_NUMBER': 2, 'IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI': 9, 'LANDSAT_SCENE_ID': 'LC81210442022047LGN00', 'WRS_PATH': 121, 'PANCHROMATIC_SAMPLES': 15361, 'PANCHROMATIC_LINES': 15661, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_Y': 5.529, 'REFLECTIVE_LINES': 7831, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_X': 5.609, 'system:asset_size': 1316371482, 'system:index': 'LC08_121044_20220216', 'DATA_SOURCE_ELEVATION': 'GLS2000', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_1': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_2': -0.1, 'DATUM': 'WGS84', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_3': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_4': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_5': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_6': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_7': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_8': -0.1, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_VERSION': 5, 'UTM_ZONE': 50, 'system:time_end': 1644979560282, 'LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID': 'LC08_L1TP_121044_20220216_20220223_02_T1', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_9': -0.1, 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_PANCHROMATIC': 15, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_4': -51.19397, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_7': 2e-05, 'system:time_start': 1644979560282, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_5': -31.32816, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_6': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_6': -7.79103, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_9': 2e-05, 'PROCESSING_SOFTWARE_VERSION': 'LPGS_15.6.0', 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7': -2.62599, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_8': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_1': -64.33729, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_2': -65.88217, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_3': -60.70986, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_1': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_8': -57.93749, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_3': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_9': -12.24375, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_2': 2e-05, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_5': 2e-05, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_4': 2e-05, 'THERMAL_LINES': 7831, 'TIRS_SSM_POSITION_STATUS': 'ESTIMATED', 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_THERMAL': 30, 'NADIR_OFFNADIR': 'NADIR', 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_11': 0.1, 'REQUEST_ID': 'P701a3ochsn1n_00028', 'EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE': 0.9878137, 'TIRS_SSM_MODEL': 'FINAL', 'SCENE_CENTER_TIME': '02:46:00.2829340Z', 'SUN_ELEVATION': 45.81495446, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10': 0.1, 'ROLL_ANGLE': -0.001, 'DATE_PRODUCT_GENERATED': 1645587523000, 'K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10': 774.8853, 'SATURATION_BAND_1': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_2': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_3': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_4': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_5': 'Y', 'MAP_PROJECTION': 'UTM', 'SATURATION_BAND_6': 'Y', 'SENSOR_ID': 'OLI_TIRS', 'SATURATION_BAND_7': 'Y', 'K1_CONSTANT_BAND_11': 480.8883, 'SATURATION_BAND_8': 'N', 'SATURATION_BAND_9': 'N', 'TARGET_WRS_PATH': 121, 'PROCESSING_LEVEL': 'L1TP', 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11': 0.0003342, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10': 0.0003342, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_MODEL': 217, 'SPACECRAFT_ID': 'LANDSAT_8', 'THERMAL_SAMPLES': 7681, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_VERIFY': 71}}
# {'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'B2', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'int', 'min': 0, 'max': 65535}, 'dimensions': [417, 410], 'origin': [328, 5444], 'crs': 'EPSG:32650', 'crs_transform': [30, 0, 192585, 0, -30, 2674215]}], 'id': 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT/LC08_121044_20220216', 'version': 1645837933973575, 'properties': {'system:footprint': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[114.10643925722704, 22.570310018167252], [114.22540059145555, 22.570310018167252], [114.22540059145555, 22.679007472112282], [114.10643925722704, 22.679007472112282], [114.10643925722704, 22.570310018167252]]]}, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5': 0.0062656, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6': 0.0015582, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3': 0.012142, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4': 0.010239, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1': 0.012867, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2': 0.013176, 'WRS_TYPE': 2, 'K2_CONSTANT_BAND_11': 1201.1442, 'K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10': 1321.0789, 'REFLECTIVE_SAMPLES': 7681, 'SUN_AZIMUTH': 140.66864157, 'DATA_SOURCE_TIRS_STRAY_LIGHT_CORRECTION': 'TIRS', 'DATE_ACQUIRED': '2022-02-16', 'ELLIPSOID': 'WGS84', 'STATION_ID': 'LGN', 'RESAMPLING_OPTION': 'CUBIC_CONVOLUTION', 'ORIENTATION': 'NORTH_UP', 'WRS_ROW': 44, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9': 0.0024488, 'TARGET_WRS_ROW': 44, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7': 0.0005252, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8': 0.011587, 'IMAGE_QUALITY_TIRS': 9, 'TRUNCATION_OLI': 'UPPER', 'CLOUD_COVER': 49.99, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_VERIFY': 6.568, 'COLLECTION_CATEGORY': 'T1', 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_REFLECTIVE': 30, 'CLOUD_COVER_LAND': 38.22, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL': 7.876, 'COLLECTION_NUMBER': 2, 'IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI': 9, 'LANDSAT_SCENE_ID': 'LC81210442022047LGN00', 'WRS_PATH': 121, 'PANCHROMATIC_SAMPLES': 15361, 'PANCHROMATIC_LINES': 15661, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_Y': 5.529, 'REFLECTIVE_LINES': 7831, 'GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL_X': 5.609, 'system:asset_size': 1316371482, 'system:index': 'LC08_121044_20220216', 'DATA_SOURCE_ELEVATION': 'GLS2000', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_1': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_2': -0.1, 'DATUM': 'WGS84', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_3': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_4': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_5': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_6': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_7': -0.1, 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_8': -0.1, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_VERSION': 5, 'UTM_ZONE': 50, 'system:time_end': 1644979560282, 'LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID': 'LC08_L1TP_121044_20220216_20220223_02_T1', 'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_9': -0.1, 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_PANCHROMATIC': 15, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_4': -51.19397, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_7': 2e-05, 'system:time_start': 1644979560282, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_5': -31.32816, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_6': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_6': -7.79103, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_9': 2e-05, 'PROCESSING_SOFTWARE_VERSION': 'LPGS_15.6.0', 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7': -2.62599, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_8': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_1': -64.33729, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_2': -65.88217, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_3': -60.70986, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_1': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_8': -57.93749, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_3': 2e-05, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_9': -12.24375, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_2': 2e-05, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_5': 2e-05, 'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_4': 2e-05, 'THERMAL_LINES': 7831, 'TIRS_SSM_POSITION_STATUS': 'ESTIMATED', 'GRID_CELL_SIZE_THERMAL': 30, 'NADIR_OFFNADIR': 'NADIR', 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_11': 0.1, 'REQUEST_ID': 'P701a3ochsn1n_00028', 'EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE': 0.9878137, 'TIRS_SSM_MODEL': 'FINAL', 'SCENE_CENTER_TIME': '02:46:00.2829340Z', 'SUN_ELEVATION': 45.81495446, 'RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10': 0.1, 'ROLL_ANGLE': -0.001, 'DATE_PRODUCT_GENERATED': 1645587523000, 'K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10': 774.8853, 'SATURATION_BAND_1': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_2': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_3': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_4': 'Y', 'SATURATION_BAND_5': 'Y', 'MAP_PROJECTION': 'UTM', 'SATURATION_BAND_6': 'Y', 'SENSOR_ID': 'OLI_TIRS', 'SATURATION_BAND_7': 'Y', 'K1_CONSTANT_BAND_11': 480.8883, 'SATURATION_BAND_8': 'N', 'SATURATION_BAND_9': 'N', 'TARGET_WRS_PATH': 121, 'PROCESSING_LEVEL': 'L1TP', 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11': 0.0003342, 'RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10': 0.0003342, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_MODEL': 217, 'SPACECRAFT_ID': 'LANDSAT_8', 'THERMAL_SAMPLES': 7681, 'GROUND_CONTROL_POINTS_VERIFY': 71}}
# Both the 'crs_transform' of band B2 are "[30, 0, 192585, 0, -30, 2674215]", it did not change before and after the clip() operation.
```

From the printed results, it can be seen that the "crs_transform" has not changed before and after the clip() operation.

The "crs_transform" list means [xScale, xShearing, xTranslation, yShearing, yScale, yTranslation]. I think the "xTranslation" and the "yTranslation" should change after the clip() operation, but they do not.

I uploaded the image after the clip() operation to EE Assets and viewed the image information. I got this:
[image]

This indicates that the "crs_transform" should change after the clip() operation.

I don't know why when I print the "crs_transform" directly with code, it remains unchanged, but when I upload the image to EE Assets and view it, I can get the correct "crs_transform". It seems that the ee.Image after the clip() operation needs to be re-uploaded to the EE Assets, then the accurate "crs_transform" after the clip() operation can be captured.

How can I use code to get accurate "crs_transform" of ee.Images after the clip() operation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of the `crs_transform` being *accurate* or not. The transform relates the coordinate system of the CRS to the coordinate system of the specific image's pixels. `clip()` does not change the coordinate system; it only masks some of the pixels — it doesn't even care what the overall bounds of the image are, old or new.

The reason the transform is different when you export to asset is that the asset ingestion process does a lot of analysis and normalization. It can afford to do that because it is an operation that always works on the *entire* image. Normal operations like `clip()` only care about the region of pixels that you request, and don't compute anything about other parts of the image — this is how Earth Engine can support interactive viewing of very large composite images at high zoom levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It made me understand the mystery behind it. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Here's another question, can I obtain the changed crs_transform after the clip() operation without saving the image? In other words,  I want to get the crs_transform value of the image after exporting the image to asset, but I don't want to export the image to asset.

Comment: @helirong I do not know of a way to do that.